# Android scene change lagging (react-native)

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build a basic app using react-native. The iOS version seems to work pretty fine, but there are some serious lags in the Android version. It is lagging only when there is a change of scene involved using the navigator. The UI in general is pretty crisp and responsive. Only changing between scenes is causing me problems. I noticed no drops in FPS during the whole process. Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed it.

```
 componentDidMount: function(){
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
      this.setState({isReady: true});
    });
}
```